# Using emacs local variables to specify a path to be used in a command

Tags: emacs, lisp, local-variables

I use emacs+AucTeX to write LaTeX files. At the bottom of the `.tex` file are some local variables:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "master-file"
%%% End:
```

These are added by AucTeX when I create the file.

What I'd like to do is write a lisp function that will do the following:

1. Check whether a particular local variable exists (call it `pdf-copy-path`)
2. If this variable exists check whether it is a well formed (unix) directory path
3. If it is, copy the output pdf to that folder

The output pdf has the same name as the current `.tex` file, but with the `.pdf` extension.

My lisp-fu isn't up to this, and I don't know how to have a function check the current file for a local variable. Any pointers appreciated.

I chose SO for this question rather than SU, because it seems to be a question about lisp programming more than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you really want a complete solution, or would rather explore more yourself, but here are a few things that should help. Post again if you're stuck:

- The variable `file-local-variables-alist` holds the values you're looking for. You'd want to use one of the `assoc` functions to get the value of pdf-copy-path out of the alist.
- You can check whether a file exists with the `file-exists-p` function, and if it's a directory with `file-attributes` (the first element).
- Then use `copy-file`.

(FWIW, I think the output PDF output will match TeX-master and not the current file.)

[Edited 2011-03-24 - provide code]

this should work on TeX files with a local variables block like

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "master"
%%% pdf-copy-path: "/pdf/copy/path"
%%% End:
```

Note the double quotes around the TeX-master value and the pdf-copy-path value. TeX-master can also be `t`

```
(defun copy-master-pdf ()
  "Copies the TeX master pdf file into the path defined by the
file-local variable `pdf-copy-path', given that both exist."
  (interactive)
  ;; make sure we have local variables, and the right ones
  (when (and (boundp 'file-local-variables-alist)
             (assoc 'pdf-copy-path file-local-variables-alist)
             (assoc 'TeX-master file-local-variables-alist))
    (let* ((path (cdr (assoc 'pdf-copy-path file-local-variables-alist)))
           (master (cdr (assoc 'TeX-master file-local-variables-alist)))
           (pdf (cond ((stringp master)
                      ;; When master is a string, it should name another file.
                       (concat (file-name-sans-extension master) ".pdf"))
                      ((and master (buffer-file-name))
                      ;; When master is t, the current file is the master.
                       (concat (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) ".pdf"))
                      (t ""))))
      (when (and (file-exists-p pdf)
                 (file-directory-p path))
        ;; The 1 tells copy-file to ask before clobbering
        (copy-file pdf path 1)))))
```

Comment: Ah. Well spotted about the TeX-master thing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a lisp novice really. So I want to use some sort of `assoc` function on `file-local...` to extract the value of the right variable, if its there. And if it's there, pass it as an argument to `copy-file` right? `assoc` gives you the _pair_ rather than the `cdr`? What I really need is a good "lisp for emacs" tutorial first...

Comment: I won't claim to be a skilled lisp coder, but the updated solution should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Excellent thanks! That works great. One thing: it might be worth updating your answer with a "use case": it took me a couple of tries to work out that I want the path to be in `"double/quotes/"`